# Natural exact sequence associated to a group/module filtration

Tags: group-theory, modules, homological-algebra, exact-sequence

Taking a group $G$ and a normal subgroup $G' \subseteq G$, we have a natural short exact sequence relating the two of them, namely:
$$ 0 \longrightarrow G' \longrightarrow G \longrightarrow G/G' \longrightarrow 0.$$

We can see this sequence as a sequence attached to the (trivial) filtration induced by $G'$, that is $0\subseteq G' \subseteq G$.

Given a generic filtration $0\subseteq G_1 \subseteq G_2 \subseteq \cdots \subseteq G_n = G$, do we have a natural way to form a long exact sequence from it?

Same goes if we replace group by $A$-module for a certain ring $A$. Is there a way to construct a long exact sequence from a module filtration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is not; long exact sequences and filtrations generalize short exact sequences in two different "directions" and are not directly related in general.  Instead, from a filtration we just have a bunch of short exact sequences $$0\to G_k \to G_{k+1}\to G_{k+1}/G_k\to 0.$$

Comment: Oh. This settles the question then. Do you have insights on the cases where such a long sequence can exist?

Comment: There aren't any such cases (besides the case $n=2$).  The closest connection between long exact sequences and filtrations is that a long exact sequence, considered as a chain complex, has a natural filtration (of chain complexes, not just of modules) obtained by truncating the sequence at different points.  (In fact, you can do this for any chain complex, not just a long exact sequence.)